# How to remove user profile completely from the Windows 10 computer?

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I want to remove local user in windows 10 computer through powershell.

I have tried command

```
Get-WMIObject -class Win32_UserProfile | Where {((!$_.Special) -and ($_.LocalPath -eq "C:\\Users\\$user")  -and ($_.LocalPath -ne "C:\\Users\\UpdatusUser"))} | Remove-WmiObject
```

The Above command removes local user sucessfully. But it can't delete `C:\Users\$user\AppData`

Is there any workaround/hack to remove user/AppData folder.

I have also tried removing folder after successful deletion of user, but I am getting an error.

Error:**There is a mismatch between the tag specified in the request and the tag present in the reparse point**

For error reference I tried some workaround on that error message none worked. But if I do shift+delete (Manually) It will delete sucessfully.

Command I am using to remove is below

```
Remove-Item C:\User\$user -Force -Recurse
```

I am running PowerShell as Administrator.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: "I am getting an error" - please add the error message in your post

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I added the error message in the post. For error reference I tried some workaround on that error message none worked. But if I do shift+delete (Manually) It will delete sucessfully.

Comment: the `reparse point` part of the error msg indicates you have some sort of redirection or other "not really here" filesystem magic going on. i don't think WMI knows how to deal with that. unfortunately, neither do it ... [*blush*]

Comment: so it is not possible to delete the AppData folder

Comment: @Vijay use cmd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:  Use cmd.

```
cmd /c rmdir /s /q c:\users\user
```

Powershell can't handle bad links in directories.  Uninstall that terrible "Office" app.  The problem is under `AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalCache`.  There's directory junctions (?) with null linktype and target properties.

Windows 10 has a unique problem in version 1809 with the "Office" app creating strangely linked files and directories under the user profile.  Even WMI can't delete the profile, nor powershell.

Wow, what kind of directory junction has no target or linktype??  But it has a ReparsePoint attribute and a mode with an "l" on the end for link.

```
get-item c:\users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub_8wekyb3d8bbwe\localcache | fl *

PSPath            : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub_8wekyb3d8bbwe\localcache
PSParentPath      : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::C:\users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub_8wekyb3d8bbwe
PSChildName       : localcache
PSDrive           : C
PSProvider        : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem
PSIsContainer     : True
Mode              : d----l
BaseName          : localcache
Target            : {}
LinkType          :
Name              : localcache
FullName          : C:\users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub_8wekyb3d8bbwe\localcache
Parent            : Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub_8wekyb3d8bbwe
Exists            : True
Root              : C:\
Extension         :
CreationTime      : 8/1/2019 3:29:02 PM
CreationTimeUtc   : 8/1/2019 7:29:02 PM
LastAccessTime    : 8/1/2019 3:29:02 PM
LastAccessTimeUtc : 8/1/2019 7:29:02 PM
LastWriteTime     : 8/1/2019 3:29:02 PM
LastWriteTimeUtc  : 8/1/2019 7:29:02 PM
Attributes        : Directory, ReparsePoint
```

Related bug report:  https://github.com/powershell/powershell/issues/621  I've seen this myself.  It takes multiple attempts in file explorer to completely delete the profile.

EDIT:

### Win 10 1809: WMI Can't Fully Delete Profiles (because of Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub)

Say I delete a profile this way:

```
Get-CimInstance win32_userprofile | where localpath -match user$ | Remove-CimInstance
```

Several folders get left over.  Here they are.  Remove-item says "is an NTFS junction point. Use the Force parameter to delete or modify this object."  Remove-item -force says "There is a mismatch between the tag specified in the request and the tag present in the reparse point"

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalCache
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalCache\Local
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalCache\Local\Microsoft
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalCache\Local\Microsoft\CLR_v4.0
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalCache\Local\Microsoft\CLR_v4.0\UsageLogs
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalCache\LocalLow
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalCache\LocalLow\Microsoft
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalCache\LocalLow\Microsoft\CryptnetUrlCache
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalCache\LocalLow\Microsoft\CryptnetUrlCache\Content
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalCache\LocalLow\Microsoft\CryptnetUrlCache\MetaData
```

Comment: I have the same problem. Is there any workout for this?

Comment: @Vijay I suspect something like `Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -online Microsoft.MicrosoftOfficeHub_8wekyb3d8bbwe`, but I haven't tried it yet.  Or remove -force the bad links.

Answer (score 0):

```
@( Get-WMIObject -class 'Win32_UserProfile' -ComputerName 'Terminal001.domain.local' )| 
    Where-Object { <**some filter conditions**> } | 
    Where-Object { $_.Special -eq $false } | 
    Where-Object { $_.Loaded  -eq $false } | 
    Where-Object { $_.Status  -eq 2 } | # We remove only local copies of Roaming profiles. We assume there is a copy of Roaming profile on a server.  
    Foreach-Object {
        $local:profile = $_;
        Write-Host -f "Gray" "Deleting $($_.LocalPath)`t" -noNewLine
        try {
            $local:profile.Delete()
            Write-Host "OK!" -f Green
        } catch {
            Write-Host -f "Yellow" "Unable to delete $($local:profile.LoalPath) : $($_.Exception.Message)"
        }
    }
```

For `Status` see docs for [Win32_UserProfile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ee886409(v%3Dvs.85)) class

Please take a note, that `LocalPath` is not always equal username. For example, if username changed while profile is created already, `LocalPath` does not change. Or, else, profile folder can be named not `Username`, but `Username.Userdomain`, or `UserName.UserDomain.nnn` (nnn - number).

Better way is to compare SIDs:

```
$userSID = (Get-ADUser 'username').SID
Get-WmiObject -Class 'Win32_UserProfile' .... |
Where-Object {$_.SID -eq $userSID} |
...
```