# Getting this "InvalidOperation" error when attempting to delete Windows user profiles

Tags: powershell, profile

I've created a PowerShell script to delete certain Windows user profiles on a remote Win7 x64 PC but I'm getting an "InvalidOperation" error. Can someone shed some light on how to remediate this?

This is my first attempt to remove Windows user profiles.

Here's my script:

```
$profiles = $null
$profiles = Get-WMIObject -class Win32_UserProfile | Where {((!$_.Special) -and ($_.LocalPath -ne "C:\Users\Administrator"))}
if ($profiles -ne $null) {
    $profiles | Remove-WMIObject
}
```

I expected the script to delete all Windows user profiles except for "Administrator" but in reality, I'm getting this error:

```
Remove-WMIObject:
At C:\Scripts\Profile_Delete_Test.ps1:5 char:17
+    $profiles | Remove-WMIObject
+
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Remove-WmiObject], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RemoveWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveWmiObject
```

Comment: I don't know if this is related.  Some of the windows apps create weird links that can't be deleted in the normal way.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57198252/how-to-remove-user-profile-completely-from-the-windows-10-computer

Comment: Are you certain that the user is logged out and does not have any processes currently running? You might want to add `-Not $_.Loaded` to your `Where-Object` clause.